# Why can 1 variable generate multiple useful features for a predictive model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models

I was reading a paper on lapse rate modeling. This page jumped out at me because of the multiple uses of some of the variables and the cross terms. It's a GLM model but I don't think that's relevant here.

- Could somebody help explain the rationale for example of having **(Issue Age)** and **(Issue Age)^2** and **log(Issue Age)** all in the same model?
- Why is it OK to have more than 1 (Issue Age) feature?
- Why not throw in **log(log(Issue Age))** and **(Issue Age)^3** too?

[image: Model sample output for a new individual's expected lapse rate.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your overall question, you put multiple features created out of one raw feature into a linear model so that the linear model can capture non-linear relationships between the feature and response.  There are bad ways to do this, ok ways to do this, and good ways to do this.  This person seems to fall into the "not-awful, but not good" bucket.

> It's a GLM model but I don't think that's relevant here.

It's definitely relevant.  This kind of thing is much less important when you are using a totally non-parametric learning algorithm like a random forest or gradient boosted tree model.  In those, it's the job of the algorithm itself to fit to the shape of the feature / response relationship.

It's going to be hard for someone to counter

> We iterated through a bunch of features and these gave the best result.

because, looking at the model, it appears that's almost certainly what was done.  This is standard in some industries (insurance in the US being one I have a lot of background in), but is not a very good way to do things.

Better would be to use non-parameteric fits like a cubic spline, and then use cross validation to tune both the number of knots (similar to the degree of the polynomial in your example), and a regularization parameter.

> Why not throw in log(log(Issue Age)) and (Issue Age)^3 too?

Probably the person fitting the model had the good sense to stop before they drastically overfit their data, even if their over all methodology is not great.

The most important thing in all this is, however you want to choose your transformations of predictors, you need to stringently validate that you are making good decisions.  The best tools of the trade here are regularization, cross validation, and the bootstrap, and all modelers should be using them.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll especially keep your last point in mind. What is it about the model result that gives a good indication that the modeler's "over all methodology is not great" without actually seeing it?

Comment: Polynomial fits of degree greater than 2 are hard to support, and have bad behaviour near the edges of data.  You've got that in a few places, even with negative exponents.  This just looks like someone went through by hand and thew a bunch at the wall to see what sticked.  It's unclear how they validated their model, or what disciplined strategy they applied to determining transformations.  I would prefer to see general spline fits when non-linear transformations of that complexity are required, they are more easily tuned and validated.

Comment: The FaceAmount predictor is also bucketed instead of treated continuously with a non-linear fit.  Breaking a predictor into buckets is a bad habit.  The Risk Class variable is another example of this, it was almost certainly derived from some other continuous model score by bucketing, why not just use the raw score?

Comment: The paper didn't specify how they determined their transformations either. Glad I asked about it, thanks again.